# A small enough delta for a collection of continuous functions

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Consider a collection of continuous functions $\{S_i:X\rightarrow X\}^{N}_{i=1}$, for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$, defined on a compact metric space $(X,\rho)$. As these functions are continuous, for a fixed $1\leq i \leq N$:

For every $z,y\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $\rho(z,y)<\delta\implies \rho(S_iz,S_iy)<\varepsilon$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. We wish to show there exists a small enough $\delta>0$ such that for all $z,y\in X$ if $\rho(z,y)<\delta\implies \rho(S_iz,S_iy)<\epsilon$ for each $1\leq i \leq N$.

---

$\underline{\textbf{Attempt:}}$

For each $1\leq i \leq N$, we can define the set, $D_i:= \{\delta_j: \text{For each pair}\ \ z,y\in X\ \ \text{if}\ \ \rho(z,y)<\delta_j\implies \rho(S_iz,S_iy)<\epsilon\}$
As each $S_i$ is assumed to be continuous, there has to exist a suitable $\delta_j$ for any given pair of $z,y$ in X. So $D_i$ cannot be empty and all of the $\delta_j$'s are bigger than zero so $D_i$ is bounded below and hence $\inf D_i$ exists.

Define $D:=\{\inf D_1,\cdots,\inf D_N\}$ and since this is a finite set, $\min D$ exists and satisfies the required condition.

---

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that this proof does not ensure that your infimums are non-zero. I think your proof would need to make use of the compactness of $X$ to circumvent this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused about where to use compactness. Since each $S_i$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, then each $S_i$ is uniformly continuous, so $D_i$ is nonempty. But it is clear that if $\delta\in D_i$ and $\eta<\delta$ then $\eta\in D_i$, so $\inf D_i=0$.

---

The solution is simpler: Given $\epsilon>0$, use uniform continuity of each $S_i$ to obtain $\delta_i$ such that
$$\text{ for all }z,y\in X,\qquad \rho(z,y)<\delta_i\Rightarrow \rho(S_iz,S_iy)<\epsilon$$

Then simply take $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_N\}$.